Ubuntu 24.04.01 installation keeps failing
I'm trying to install Ubuntu 24.04.01, but the setup keeps failing. I tried running the setup normally. I tried running it in safe graphics mode. I tried it with and without manual partitioning. It just keeps failing. I even redownloaded the setup file, made a bootable USB stick with it all over again. I fully formatted my SSD just to be sure. It still keeps failing, and I have no clue of the source of issue. I've attached two screenshots of when the setup encountered the error.
I'm also pasting the log in case it helps narrow down the problem.
Full error log is here: log file
Nov 24 15:45:21 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]:
subiquity/load_cloud_config/extract_autoinstall:
Nov 24 15:45:23 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]:
subiquity/load_cloud_config/extract_autoinstall:
Nov 24 15:45:24 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]: subiquity/Early/apply_autoinstall_config:
Nov 24 15:45:24 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]: subiquity/Early/apply_autoinstall_config:
Nov 24 15:45:24 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]:
subiquity/Reporting/apply_autoinstall_config:
Nov 24 15:45:24 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]:
subiquity/Reporting/apply_autoinstall_config:
Nov 24 15:45:24 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]: subiquity/Error/apply_autoinstall_config:
Nov 24 15:45:24 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]: subiquity/Error/apply_autoinstall_config:
Nov 24 15:45:24 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]: subiquity/Userdata/apply_autoinstall_config:
Nov 24 15:45:24 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]: subiquity/Userdata/apply_autoinstall_config:
Nov 24 15:45:24 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]: subiquity/Package/apply_autoinstall_config:
Nov 24 15:45:24 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]: subiquity/Package/apply_autoinstall_config:
Nov 24 15:45:24 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]: subiquity/Debconf/apply_autoinstall_config:
Nov 24 15:45:24 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]: subiquity/Debconf/apply_autoinstall_config:
Nov 24 15:45:24 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]: subiquity/Kernel/apply_autoinstall_config:
Nov 24 15:45:24 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]: subiquity/Kernel/apply_autoinstall_config:
Nov 24 15:45:24 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]: subiquity/Zdev/apply_autoinstall_config:
Nov 24 15:45:24 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]: subiquity/Zdev/apply_autoinstall_config:
Nov 24 15:45:24 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]: subiquity/Ad/apply_autoinstall_config:
Nov 24 15:45:24 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]: subiquity/Ad/apply_autoinstall_config:
Nov 24 15:45:24 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]: subiquity/Late/apply_autoinstall_config:
Nov 24 15:45:24 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]: subiquity/Late/apply_autoinstall_config:
Nov 24 15:50:50 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]: subiquity/Ad/has_support_GET:
Nov 24 15:51:17 ubuntu subiquity_event.4229[4229]: configuring apt
Nov 24 15:51:28 ubuntu subiquity_log.4229[6422]: start: cmd-apt-config: curtin command apt-config
Nov 24 15:51:28 ubuntu subiquity_log.4229[6422]: Handling apt to target /tmp/tmpig7_yojy/mount
with config {'debconf_selections': {'subiquity': ''}, 'disable_components': [], 'preserve_sources_list':
False, 'primary': [{'arches': ['default'], 'uri': 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/'}], 'security':
[{'arches': ['amd64', 'i386'], 'uri': 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/'}, {'arches': ['s390x', 'arm64',
'armhf', 'powerpc', 'ppc64el', 'riscv64'], 'uri': 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports'}]}
Nov 24 15:51:28 ubuntu subiquity_log.4229[6422]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/dev',
'/tmp/tmpig7_yojy/mount/dev'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Nov 24 15:51:28 ubuntu subiquity_log.4229[6422]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/proc',
'/tmp/tmpig7_yojy/mount/proc'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Nov 24 15:51:28 ubuntu subiquity_log.4229[6422]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/run',
'/tmp/tmpig7_yojy/mount/run'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Nov 24 15:51:28 ubuntu subiquity_log.4229[6422]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/sys',
'/tmp/tmpig7_yojy/mount/sys'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Nov 24 15:51:28 ubuntu subiquity_log.4229[6422]: Running command ['mount', '--bind',
'/sys/firmware/efi/efivars', '/tmp/tmpig7_yojy/mount/sys/firmware/efi/efivars'] with allowed return
codes [0] (capture=False)
Nov 24 15:51:28 ubuntu subiquity_log.4229[6422]: Running command ['mount', '--bind',
'/tmp/tmpig7_yojy/mount/usr/bin/true', '/tmp/tmpig7_yojy/mount/usr/bin/ischroot'] with allowed
return codes [0] (capture=False)
Nov 24 15:51:28 ubuntu subiquity_log.4229[6422]: Running command ['unshare', '--help'] with
allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)

System problem detected:


Single operating system or sharing with Windows. BIOS or UEFI boot.

single os and UEFI

Try accessing the BIOS by pressing F2 repeatedly as soon as the computer starts up and before any operating system loads. Once you're in the BIOS, find the "Secure Boot" setting and disable it. Then, save the changes and try booting from the USB again. Alternatively, you can try creating a new Linux Ubuntu bootable USB drive. Ensure that the ISO file you're using is not corrupted and that the USB drive itself is functioning properly.

the secure boot is already disabled

Start a live session of Ubuntu.
Once the boot is complete, open a terminal and run:
sudo apt install gparted
sudo gparted

From gparted, select the hard drive.
Unmount it if it is mounted.
Create a new gpt partition table.
In the free space, create a 512-megabyte partition, Efi-Boot partition (Fat32).
Next, create a 60-gigabyte partition, ext4 system.
Create another 8-gigabyte partition, swap system.
Create another remaining partition that you plan to use for Linux, ext4 system.
Apply the changes.
Close gparted.
Close the terminal.
Start the installation.
Choose manual partitioning.
Grub by default on the hard drive.
The 60-gigabyte partition for /
The 8-gigabyte partition for swap.
The remaining one for /home.
Continue with the installation.
